# TeamCity test failure statistics

Tags: teamcity, automated-tests

I have a TeamCity build set up which does nothing but run integration tests. Sadly, the tests are a tad unreliable. Most of them work fine, but a few intermittently fail from time to time.

I would dearly love to be able to get a graph of the most common test failures. Basically I want to know which tests fail most often.

I know that TC can show me pass/fail statistics for any single test. But I'm not going to go click on all 400+ tests to find out which ones fail most often!

If it's not possible to make TC show me this information, is there some interface that will enable me to download the data so I can process it myself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get count on frequently of fail test details from teamcity by following steps as details in this link:

Traverse with route : `Projects -> (select proj) -> Current Problems (tab) -> View tests failed within the last 120hrs (link present at right side of page )`

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Viewing+Tests+and+Configuration+Problems#ViewingTestsandConfigurationProblems-ViewingTestsFailedwithinLast120Hours

Comment: I can't find this. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place. When I view a particular project, I see Overview | History | Change Log | Issue Log | Statistics | Compatible Agents | Pending Changes | Settings. I don't see a Current Problems tab anywhere. (TeamCity 8.0.2)

Comment: Hold on, I found it. You have to go to the page for a _project_, not a _build_. (I never ever do that. I only ever look at the all-builds page, or the page for a specific build. I didn't even realise there _was_ a page for a sub-project!)

Comment: This only displays for the last 120 hours, please see my answer and you can see alot more details

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a better way than the accepted answer, for version 9 at least.

In a failed build "overview" page like this:

[image]

You can click on the test history button in the small drop down menu

You will then be presented with a view like this:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't accomplish what was asked for -- note the OP says: "I know that TC can show me pass/fail statistics for any single test. But I'm not going to go click on all 400+ tests to find out which ones fail most often!"